# Heroku: Replacement for Anvil builds?

Tags: c++, heroku

I used to use Anvil (through hammer) to build some native libs to be bundled with a rails app. Specifically I was building libapngasm using this:
https://github.com/Kagetsuki/heroku-buildpack-apngasm

Unfortunately it seems Anvil has been discontinued and I couldn't find any information on how to do a remote build and retrieve the resulting binaries through the Build API.

Is there a new alternative to Anvil? What is a "correct" way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the official answer here was a little more obvious than I had expected. Basically if you're running the same gcc/libc~ as that stack your dyno is running compile locally. Otherwise just spin up a VM or a docker image with a compatible version and build on that. Then just vendorize the libraries/binaries into your app repository so they'll be bundled up with the slug when you push. Finally, set your heroku environment load path to find the libs/bins you bundled.